# Ciclo repetitivo javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql

buenas noches, tengo esta vista (la de la imagen) la cual forma parte de una factura, precisamente este es el detalle de la factura, y tengo en este detalle una funcion javascript para que mientras yo escribo el nombre del producto me busque el producto en la base de datos y cuando lo selecciono me llena el input del precio unidad correspondiente a ese producto, hasta ahi todo de maravillas, pero el problema es que al pulsar el boton de + para introducir una nueva linea y cargar un nuevo producto la funcion de javascript ya no funciona, se me ocurrio que puedo usar un foreach o algo similar que haga funcionar esa funcion cada vez que se inserta una nueva linea pero no logro hacerlo funcionar, les dejo el codigo: 
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
//metodo para buscar en la base de datos
$("#inputPrecioProducto").devbridgeAutocomplete({
        showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
        serviceUrl: '/maderas/facturar/leer_productos',
        noSuggestionNotice: 'No se encontraron datos',
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            $('#inputIdProducto').val(suggestion.data)
            $('#inputPrecioUnidad').val(suggestion.precio_unidad);
        }
    });}
```

// Repetidor de campos de Productos

$('.repeater').repeater({
            hide: function (deleteElement) {
            var elemento=$(this);
            swal({   
                title: "Estas Seguro?",   
                text: "Se borrará toda la fila!",   
                type: "warning",   
                showCancelButton: true,   
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
                confirmButtonText: "Si, bórralo!",
                cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',   
                closeOnConfirm: false
            }, function(){   

                swal("Producto Borrado!", "Se ha eliminado el Producto.", "success"); 

                elemento.remove();
                sumarTotales();
                crearIgv();
            });

        },
        isFirstItemUndeletable: true

    });
// ./ Repetidor de campos de Productos

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Tengo la sospecha de que lo que te está pasando es que se están creando nuevos elementos al añadir una fila nueva y esos elementos no tienen los eventos asociados correspondientes. Podrías confirmar que ese es el caso?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la función javascript para el botón '+' ?

Comment: la funcion para el boton '+' es la funcion .repeater que mencione arriba

Comment: Eso es lo que yo pienso, que al crear filas nuevas no tengo asociado el evento de autocompletado, pero no se como asociarlo a cada linea que agregue

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema, tal y como se especifica en el comentario que te han dejado, es que el evento asociado a la búsqeda no se le asigna al nuevo campo que generas cuando le das al más. 
Si te fijas, en la función de tu javascript que se encarga del autocompletado, cuando haces el selector con JQuery lo haces refiriendote a un id en concreto.

```
$("#inputPrecioProducto").devbridgeAutocomplete({...});
```

Para solucionarlo te aconsejo que utilices clases para referirte a los componentes que deban tener la funcion de autocompletado. Cuando crees el imput nuevo añadele la clase: `class="autocompletado"` por ejemplo, y cambia el selector que haces para referirte a estos inputs:

```
$(".autocompletado").devbridgeAutocomplete({...});
```

De esta forma el evento deautocompletado actuará sobre todos los inputs que pertenezcan a la clase "autocompletado".

Comment: De todas formas no funciona así, cuando hace la selección jQuery solo engloba todo lo que haya a la hora de cargar el documento con la clase `autocompletado` y cualquier elemento agregado dinámicamente no tendrá su evento.

Comment: Cierto, debería recargar el evento, o definirlo a la hora de crear el componente: `onchange="funcionAutocompletado()"`

Comment: deberia llamar a la funcion de autocompletado mediante onchange?

Comment: Perdón corrijo, mediante onkeyup, de esta forma cada vez que dejes de presionar una letra hará la búsqueda (deberías por tanto comprobar el length del input para evitarte hacer peticiones cuando el usuario lleve pocas letras escritas). Mas info aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

Comment: no me funciono tampoco con el onkeyup

Comment: Muchisimas gracias igual por los aportes